# Outputdebugstring, printf not work(Visual studio 2012, Windows 8)

Tags: c++, debugging, window

I'm using Visual studio 2012 on Windows 8.

I usually use OutputDebugString for logging, but recently it doesn't work.

I reinstall visual studio too, but it was same.

Now I can do logging with only fprintf!! It's really painful....

Anyone has solution about this problem?

-- my code --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    OutputDebugString( L"hello world" );
    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I made new project right now, 
This project's printf is work well. But OutputDebugString still doesn't work.

And my cocos2dx project( yeah, i'm working on cocos2dx ), it's both printf and OutputDebugString doesn't work!!

Comment: Please post code to show what you mean

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I uploaded my code.

Comment: Did you see  `Debug` window's output?

Comment: Of course. I saw many windows in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system debug print filter is set to allow all messages, typically done by setting the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter` to DWORD 0xFFFFFFFF.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519(v=vs.85).aspx for more.

Comment: Nope.... There isn't value lkie Debug Print Filter in Session Manager registry....

Comment: I don't think it exists by default, but you can create it.

Comment: Did not do anything for me